# AttributeError: 'Linkedlist' object has no attribute 'printLinkedlist' ==> Linked list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

Here, I am could understand what is wrong I am doing, I getting error as below.. can anyone help me, please. I am new at Python.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/Code_example/Code/linkedlist/ll4.py", line 37, in 
a.printLinkedlist()
AttributeError: 'Linkedlist' object has no att
Code Details :

```
   class Node:
        def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
            self.data = data
            self.next = next
        
        def printLinkedlist(self):
            temp = self.head
            while temp:
               print(temp.data, end=' ')
               temp = temp.next
    
    class Linkedlist:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
    
        def append(self, new_data):
            new_node = Node(new_data)
    
            if self.head == None:
                self.head = new_node
                return
    
            last_node = self.head 
            
            while last_node.next:
            
                last_node = last_node.next
    
            last_node.next = new_node
    
    
    a = Linkedlist()
    a.append(1)
    
    a.printLinkedlist()
```

Comment: As your error suggests, your `a` object which is a `LinkedList` doesn't have a `printLinkedlist` method. Your `Node` object does. `a.head` which is an instance of `Node` would have a `printLinkedlist` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of relationships between objects. There are a few places where you refer to a `Linkedlist` method or attribute within your `Node` class.

Your `Node` class knows nothing about your `Linkedlist` class since there are no references to it within the class.

`a = Linkedlist()` creates an instance of `Linkedlist`. Therefore the only methods you can call on it are methods within the class definition.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    
    # I changed head to an arg since
    # it's the easiest way to pass it to the Node object
    def printLinkedlist(self, head):
        temp = head
        while temp:
           print(temp.data, end=' ')
           temp = temp.next

class Linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)

        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last_node = self.head 
        
        while last_node.next:        
            last_node = last_node.next

        last_node.next = new_node


a = Linkedlist()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.append(3)
# here we get the head node object you stored within your LinkedList class
head_node = a.head
# the node object DOES have a printLinkedlist method
# so we can call it on that
head_node.printLinkedlist(head_node)
```